Do I have any legal avenues if someone drives with an obnoxiously loud motor vehicle through a city in Sweden?
Sometimes when I'm in the city someone will drive through the streets with a car that's obviously been modified to be obnoxiously loud, often enough to be heard several blocks away. Is there anything a regular citizen can do about such a motor vehicle assuming they know the letter and number combination on the registration plate? That is, are there any laws forbidding such modification of vehicles, and if so, is there anywhere I can report this potential legal offence?

Ask your local police department

I cannot answer for Sweden, but in Germany this modification would be illegal. If the police find out, they will prohibit any further use of the vehicle until it passes specs again. So one might inform the police, who should follow up on this lead as soon as they have the time. Could be tomorrow, could be a very long time.

Most places have "distubing the peace" ordinances regarding excessive noise, and even stricter rules at night.

You probably can't file a lawsuit against the driver, and even if you could it would be uneconomic. What would the economic value of your harm be for 15-30 seconds of elevated noise? It may violate some Swedish law, either a general noise ordinance, or a vehicle modification ordinance, that a prosecutor could press charges against the owner/driver for, usually through the intermediary of the local police department. But lacking access to the relevant Swedish legal references, I won't post an answer. Even if it didn't violate a law, a cop night warn someone that people dislike their conduct.

Thanks for the answers everyone. When I wrote this I didn't really realise what I was asking in hindsight, but I agree that suing over something like this would be silly. Notifying the police department seems reasonable and probably something I should've thought of myself.
